# Is the "recovery phrase" generated by a wallet app platform independent?

Tags: wallet-recovery, bip32-hd-wallets, mnemonic-seed

I recently started a wallet with Coinbase Wallet, and I was asked to backup a 12 word "recovery phrase" that is supposed to be able to recover my wallet in the event that I delete the app from my phone. I have previously used other wallet apps, which often give "recovery phrases" of varying word count. I read online that the phrase is passed through an algorithm and used to recover a key or a group of keys.

I am now curious if these recovery phrases are platform independent (meaning you can recover your keys just by way of knowing the phrase), or if the app must exist with a specific algorithm in order to recover keys (your keys are lost if the recovery implementation is destroyed, e.g. Coinbase shuts down operation and removes their app).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The mnemonic words that is given to you by the wallets is a representation of entropy. This entropy is then passed through PBKDF2 hashing function to generate seed. The industry standard for this conversion of mnemonic to seed is documented in [BIP 39](https://github.com/bitcoin/bips/blob/master/bip-0039.mediawiki) and most wallets follow that method. The seed is then passed to `HMAC-SHA512` to get a master extended private key.

Until this point the implementations are standard and you are unlikely to face any issue with different wallet implementations. But after this step, the derivation gets a bit trickier. There are a number of methods to go from here. You could use [BIP 32](https://github.com/bitcoin/bips/blob/master/bip-0032.mediawiki), [BIP 44](https://github.com/bitcoin/bips/blob/master/bip-0044.mediawiki), [BIP 49](https://github.com/bitcoin/bips/blob/master/bip-0049.mediawiki) or the [BIP 84](https://github.com/bitcoin/bips/blob/master/bip-0084.mediawiki) derivation methods to generate individual private keys from the master private key. Then there will be distinction between hardened and non-hardened derivation between different wallets. Each derivation path will give you a completely different set of keys as compared to other paths.

There is a spreadsheet tracking these derivation paths of numerous wallets [here](https://onedrive.live.com/view.aspx?resid=584F122BA17116EE!313&app=Excel) (please verify the data yourself as it may be dated or incorrect). I have pasted the derivation paths of different wallets below from the linked spreadsheet.

[image]

So, when using a wallet you should note the derivation path the wallet followed in order to recover it later. Also note that use of a passphrase along with the mnemonic words will generate a completely different set of keys as compared to only using the mnemonic words.